# How can i compute a result from related models in django

Tags: python, django, backend

```
class Function(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Fractions(models.Model):
  fraction = models.DecimalField( max_digits = 5,decimal_places = 2)
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.fraction)

 class Project(models.Model):
    func= models.ForeignKey(Function, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    fraction= models.ForeignKey(Fraction, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ratio = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=200)
```

What i am trying to do if Function.name equals = "x" multiply specific Fractions.fraction by 4 and assign the result to ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ratio` depends entirely on the `Function` and `Fraction`, it makes not much sense to store this. Then you can just implement this as a propery, like:

```
class Function(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def evaluate(self, x):
        if self.name == 'x':
            return 4 * x
        return x

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Fraction(models.Model):
    fraction = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fraction)


class Project(models.Model):
    func = models.ForeignKey(Function, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    fraction = models.ForeignKey(Fraction, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @property
    def ratio(self):
        if self.func is not None and self.fraction is not None:
            return self.func.evaluate(self.fraction.fraction)
```

It will thus determine the ratio by fetching the `Function` object, and calling `.evaluate(…)`. In case the name is `x`, it will return the value times four, otherwise it will return the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Function`s names are unique:

```
project = Project.objects.get(func__name='x')
return project.fraction.fraction * project.ratio
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers, you can use python's [operator library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) to perform the operations and insert them into a dict. I would suggest combining this with `choices`  on your name field - though note the choice cannot be an operator function but a string value.

```py
import operator 

FUNCTIONS = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv
}

class Function(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def evaluate(self, a, b)
        op = FUNCTIONS.get(self.name)
        if op:
            return op(a, b)
        return None
```